# hsperfdata_uid folder not getting created

Tags: java, virtual-machine

I am trying to use jstat and jmap utilities to get the snapshot of the jvm. It is working fine in dev and staging env but it doesn't work in production. All three on linux.
The error is 'could not find jvmId'. The main difference i found is that the on prod jvm is not creating a /tmp/hsperfdata_uid folder but on dev env i can see the files created under hsperfdata_uid for each jvm. 
   I am not able to figure out the difference between these settings in these JVMs. I tried using -XX:+UsePerfData on that jvm but still no output.

let me know if you guys had any such issues.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the exact same Java VM (installed exactly the same way like on dev / staging)?
Also check the users permission who is executing the JVM.
And do compare the environment variables when executing the JVM.
Last I would check the size and access rights to the /tmp file system. Also check if it uses the same file system type (sometimes temp uses tmpfs or sth similar and often /tmp has limited space available.

Hope these pointers help to figure out whats going wrong!
Greetings
-Sascha-